# Extract elements of matrix in expression

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to extract elements from matrix in one expression for slicing operators:

```
([1 2 3; 4 5 6] * [1 2 3]') (1:2)
```

Without using intermediate variable

```
tmp=[1 2 3; 4 5 6] * [1 2 3]';

tmp(1:2)
```

Comment: (1) I'm not sure that via "subsref" it is possible to exrtact rows&columns from matrix. (2) I'm interesting in language expressions mostly (3) Right now I'm working in matlab 2015. Post was created at 2011 year.

Comment: Matlab still does not allow direct indexing of literals; the duplicate is still the best Matlab can do.